# Recursive delete files using perl script

Tags: perl, recursion, ftp, rmdir

I would like to delete all the file in a directory using only "rmdir" in perl script.
I'm trying to clean up a directory first and then trying to write file.
I know i can just use rmtree (" directory path"); but i'm unable to use that for FTP server (use Net::FTP;). and rmdir looks for empty directory. 
i have tried "remove_tree" and "rm -rf". i do have read/write access to the server, but i'm unable to delete files.

Perl script:

```
finddepth (\&remove_dir, "$path");
rmdir ( "$path" ) or die ("Could not remove $path");

sub remove_dir
{
  # for a path, this will be 0
  if ( ! (stat("$File::Find::name"))[7] ) 
  { $ftp->rmdir("$File::Find::name"); }
  else
  { $ftp->unlink("$File::Find::name"); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ftp->rmdir($dir_name, 1);
```

[https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::FTP#rmdir-DIR-RECURSE](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aFTP#rmdir-DIR-RECURSE)

Comment: thanks Sergei Svistunov, i did try that. I does half a job, it skips saying directory is not empty.

Comment: Perhaps it didn't have permission to delete some of the files? Or maybe the FTP server hides some of the files from the client (such as those with a leading `.`)?